# error-detection for file sent across a network - can only link to pthread and math library in c

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, error-detection

I need to transfer a file from one host to another but the data can be corrupted in between so I need to have some error detection algorithm . So i thought I could send the md5 sum along but my assignment does not allow. we  can only linke to pthread and the math libraries. I know one of the way is to use CRC but it wil get time consuming . Is there any way I can use some in-built function call and get done something similar to md5 or a checksum ?

Edit: I called the sendto function provided in the assignment which may corrupt the data and then send it.

Comment: You do know that TCP/IP already have checksums on their packages?

Comment: Why do you think that CRC will be "time consuming" ? It's cheaper to calculate than md5.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : I am not using raw sockets so how can I have access to the IP checksum. Can you let me know how can we access that ? I am using a basic SOCK_DGRAM socket.

Comment: @PaulR : I kind of dont want to implement CRC because thats not the main aim of our assignment. I thought MD5 was directly available from library so I could use it. Is there any other option i  can use given my linking limitations

Comment: What I'm saying is that you don't _need_ your own checksum, as the underlying protocol already handles it for you. If you receive a packet, you know it will be correct.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : the problem here is I call mp3sendto function provided in my assignment and they kind of garbled the data and send it so I think in that case the IP checksum will not be useful to me and I need to have my own. My bad I should have told you this before.

Comment: I think you have a complete other problem, that's not network related. Maybe you read/write the files using text mode when it should be binary mode? Or you use string functions on the binary data?

Comment: No the thing is to send a packet I created I give call to mp3_sendto (which  is provided as a library function in our assignment) this function then may change my orignal data and send it to the other end. my aim is at the other end I should be able to detect if my data was garbled by mp3_sendto

Comment: Implementing a simple CRC function should be quite trivial and will not take very long. You can probably find any number of CRC routines in C on the web that you can use without any great investment of effort.

Comment: Ah, it's a _deliberate_ garbling, to test your skills in detecting it. A simple CRC might be enough. Should be easy to find anywhere. Just add the checksum as a fixed-size field either first or at the end of the actual data, and send it as a single packet.